# Why object inside an array not being garbage collected

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

`===` checks the object equality based on references, then why setting `object = null` not changing the same object referenced inside an array ?

```js
let john = {
  name: "John"
};

let array = [john];

console.log(array[0] === john); // true

john = null; // set john to null 

console.log(array[0] === john); // false -- why not true ?

console.log(array[0]); // {name: "John"} -- why not null ?
```

Comment: GC only occurs once nothing more can reference the variable, *and* after a delay. `array[0]` still has a reference to the object. (There's no way to even determine via JS if GC has occurred - it's invisible to the implementation, other than if you get an OOM error)

Comment: This has nothing to do with garbage collection. That `array[0] === john` is the same as `array[0] === null`.  `array[0]` is a reference to the same object as `john` once ___referenced___

Comment: First log returns true as you are comparing same object's reference. When you do `john = null`, you are updating pointer in `john` to some other location, so original content of `john` is still intact and is referred by `array[0]`. Hence `john` is null but not `array[0]`

Comment: @koolm, please be aware that `===` checks for __identity__. If you want to check equality, you use `==`. [Comparaison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: After changing object john value to null, it reference is change, therefore it will give false for comparision array[0] === john

Comment: I was thinking by setting object = null I am setting object to the null value, and not the pointer of that object, Thanks for all the explanations!!

Comment: `// This line does three different things: creates an anonymous object in memory, create a variable named "john", and set the value of this variable to the reference to the anonymous object`
`let john = { name: "John" };`

Comment: `// This line copies the value of the variable name "john" (i.e. the reference to the anonymous object) as the first item a new array. There is no link between this array and the variable "john" once the value has been copied`
`let array = [john];`

Comment: `// The comparison is between the VALUE of the first item of the array and the VALUE of the variable "john"`
`console.log(array[0] === john); // true`

Comment: `// This line change the value of the variable named "john" to null. Nothing happens in the array.`
`john = null; // set john to null`

Comment: `// The value of the first item of the array is still the reference to the anonymous object, the value of the variable "john" is null`
`console.log(array[0] === john);
console.log(array[0]);`

Comment: And since you were wondering about garbage collection, as long as the array still holds a reference to the anonymous object, this will not be garbage collected. If you set `array[0] = null`, you will delete the last reference to the object: you won't be able to access this object anymore and it probably will be garbage collected as some point.

Comment: wow @giuseppedeponte now it's super clear.. Thanks lot.!!